# Массив с картинками (рулетка) , как сделать все картинки одного размера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: РУЛЕТКА С ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕМ]

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({

    roulette: function(options) {

      var defaults = {
        angle: 0,
        angleOffset: -45,
        speed: 5000,
        easing: "easeInOutElastic",
      };  

      var opt = $.extend(defaults, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        var o = opt;

        var data = [
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'},
          { img: 'url(https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/t9r2n8jiek3touucngxw.png)'}
        ];


        var $wrap = $(this),
            $btnStart = $wrap.find("#btn-start"),
            $roulette = $wrap.find(".roulette"),
            wrapW = $wrap.width(),
            angle = o.angle,
            angleOffset = o.angleOffset,
            speed = o.speed,
            esing = o.easing,
            itemSize = data.length,
            itemSelector = "item",
            labelSelector = "label",
            d = 360 / itemSize,
            borderTopWidth = wrapW,
            borderRightWidth = tanDeg(d);

        for(i=1; i<=itemSize; i+=1){
          var idx = i-1,
              rt = i*d + angleOffset,
              itemHTML = $('<div class="'+ itemSelector +'">'),
              labelHTML = '';
              

          $roulette.append(itemHTML);
          $roulette.children("."+ itemSelector).eq(idx).append(labelHTML);
          $roulette.children("."+ itemSelector).eq(idx).css({
            "left": wrapW / 2,
            "top": -wrapW / 2,
            "border-top-width": borderTopWidth,
            "border-right-width": borderRightWidth,
            "background-image": data[idx].img,
            "background-position": "center center",
            "transform": "rotate("+ rt + "deg)"
          });

          var textH = parseInt(((2*Math.PI*wrapW)/d)*.5);

        }

        function tanDeg(deg) {
          var rad = deg * Math.PI/180;
          return wrapW / (1/Math.tan(rad));
        }


        $btnStart.on("click", function() {
          rotation();
        });

        function rotation() {

          var completeA = 360 * r(5, 10) + r(0, 360);

          $roulette.rotate({
            angle: angle,
            animateTo: completeA,
            center: ["50%", "50%"],
            easing: $.easing.esing,
            callback: function() {
              var currentA = $(this).getRotateAngle();

              console.log(currentA);

            },
            duration: speed
          });
        }

        function r(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

  $('.box-roulette').roulette();

});
```

```css
html, body, button{
 font-family:Arial, "돋움", Dotum, "굴림", Gulim, "Apple SD Gothic Neo", AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

button{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;}

.title{margin-top:50px;text-align:center;}

.box-roulette {
 position:relative;
 margin:50px auto;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 border:10px solid #ccc;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#ccc;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.box-roulette .markers{
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:0;
 margin-left:-25px;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 border:25px solid #fff;
 border-left-color:transparent;
 border-right-color:transparent;
 border-bottom-color:transparent;
 z-index:9999;
}
.box-roulette .roulette{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.box-roulette .item{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 border:0 solid transparent;
 transform-origin:0 100%;
}
.box-roulette .label{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 white-space:nowrap;
 transform-origin:0 0;
}
.box-roulette .label .text{
 display:inline-block;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 line-height:1;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

#btn-start{

 position:absolute;
 left:100%;top:50%;
 margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:50px;
 z-index:9999;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.sobekrepository.org/includes/jquery-rotate/2.2/jquery-rotate.min.js"></script>



    <p class="title">РУЛЕТКА</p>
    <div class="box-roulette">
    <div class="markers"></div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-start">   TAP ME
    </button>
    <div class="roulette" id="roulette"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: это не вы делали ?

Comment: нет, я просто пытаюсь изменить его

Comment: не могу понять почему 1 картинка больше а остальные одного размера

Comment: @ЖанибекАхметбек там все картинки одного размера. Просто каждая следующая накладывается сверху на предыдущую. А на последнюю никакая не накладывается. Поэтому такой эффект.